# How to do recursion in anonymous fn, without tail recursion

Tags: recursion, functional-programming, clojure, lisp, tail-recursion

How do I do recursion in an anonymous function, without using tail recursion?

For example (from Vanderhart 2010, p 38):

```
(defn power
  [number exponent]
  (if (zero? exponent)
    1
    (* number (power number (- exponent 1)))))
```

Let's say I wanted to do this as an anonymous function. And for some reason I didn't want to use tail recursion. How would I do it? For example:

```
( (fn [number exponent] ......))))) 5 3)
125
```

Can I use **loop** for this, or can loop only be used with **recur**?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The `fn` special form gives you the [option to provide a name](http://clojure.org/special_forms#Special%20Forms--%28fn%20name?%20%5Bparams*%20%5D%20exprs*%29) that can be used internally for recursion.

```
(doc fn)
;=> (fn name? [params*] exprs*)
```

So, add "power" as the name to complete your example.

```
(fn power [n e]
  (if (zero? e)
    1
    (* n (power n (dec e)))))
```

Even if the recursion happened in the tail position, it will not be optimized to replace the current stack frame. Clojure enforces you to be explicit about it with `loop`/`recur` and `trampoline`.

Comment: Thanks Jeremy, I didn't know about the name option. I'm working through the [4clojure](http://www.4clojure.com/) questions and they don't allow defn. Tail recursion is obviously better, but I want to walk before I run :)

Answer (score 18):

I know that in Clojure there's syntactic support for "naming" an anonymous function, as other answers have pointed out. However, I want to show a first-principles approach to solve the question, one that does not depend on the existence of special syntax on the programming language and that would work on any language with first-order procedures (lambdas).

In principle, if you want to do a recursive function call, you need to refer to the name of the function so "anonymous" (i.e. *nameless* functions) can not be used for performing a recursion ... unless you use the [Y-Combinator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Y-combinator). [Here](http://www.fatvat.co.uk/2009/04/understanding-y-combinator.html)'s an explanation of how it works in Clojure.

Let me show you how it's used with an example. First, a `Y-Combinator` that works for functions with a variable number of arguments:

```
(defn Y [f]
  ((fn [x] (x x))
   (fn [x]
       (f (fn [& args]
              (apply (x x) args))))))
```

Now, the *anonymous* function that implements the `power` procedure as defined in the question. Clearly, it doesn't have a name, `power` is only a parameter to the outermost function:

```
(fn [power]
      (fn [number exponent]
          (if (zero? exponent)
              1
              (* number (power number (- exponent 1))))))
```

Finally, here's how to apply the `Y-Combinator` to the anonymous `power` procedure, passing as parameters `number=5` and `exponent=3` (it's not tail-recursive BTW):

```
((Y 
  (fn [power]
      (fn [number exponent]
          (if (zero? exponent)
              1
              (* number (power number (- exponent 1)))))))
 5 3)

> 125
```

Comment: Gracias Óscar. The Y-Combinator looks very interesting - I'm going to study it more!

Comment: Another good source for understanding the Y combinator is [The Little Schemer](https://mitpress.mit.edu/books/little-schemer).

Answer (score 4):

`fn` takes an [optional name argument](http://clojure.org/special_forms#Special%20Forms--%28fn%20name?%20%5Bparams%2a%20%5D%20exprs%2a%29) that can be used to call the function recursively.

E.g.:

```
user> ((fn fact [x]
           (if (= x 0)
               1
               (* x (fact (dec x)))))
       5)
;; ==> 120
```

Comment: Thanks Greg, it seems the name option is the way to go.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can use `loop` for this. `recur` works in both `loop`s and `fn`s

```
user> (loop [result 5 x 1] (if (= x 3) result (recur (* result 5) (inc x))))
125
```

an idomatic clojure solution looks like this:

```
user> (reduce * (take 3 (repeat 5)))
125
```

or uses Math.pow() ;-)

```
user> (java.lang.Math/pow 5 3)
125.0
```

Comment: But the question was "without doing tail recursion" :-)

Answer (score 0):

[loop](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/loop) can be a recur target, so you could do it with that too.

Comment: But the question was "without doing tail recursion" :-)

Comment: :-) I kknow, but recur does not do recursion, the compiler will fixup a loop for you (even in the tail recursion situation). So sort of not.